# Normalizing line endings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, newline, line-breaks

I have a string in Ruby, `s` (say) which might have any of the standard line endings (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`). I want to convert all of those to `\n`s. What's the best way?

This seems like a super-common problem, but there's not much documentation about it. Obviously there are easy crude solutions, but is there anything built in to handle this?

*Elegant, idiomatic-Ruby solutions are best.*

EDIT: realized that `^M` and `\r` are the same. But there are still three cases. (See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Best is just to handle the two cases that you want to change specifically and not try to get too clever:

```
s.gsub /\r\n?/, "\n"
```

Comment: Two things: You have to put \r\n first in the regex or else it will never match (because anyhing that could otherwise matched b \r\n will be matched by \r first). And '\n' == "\\n", while what you want is "\n".

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes. Otherwise it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: It seems we're all on the same page :)

Comment: nicely done that you don't bother changing the default case (`\n` -> `\n` is unnecessary. didn't quite realise this at first :)

Comment: Interesting answer; I wonder why Ruby doesn't have something like python's `os.linesep`?

Comment: it would be cool to have an answer that utilized this line of code. All the details around File, readline, etc. The context of what this line fits into

Answer (score 44):

Since ruby 1.9 you can use [`String::encode`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-encode) with `universal_newline: true` to get all of your new lines into `\n` while keeping your encoding unchanged:

```
s.encode(s.encoding, universal_newline: true)
```

Once in a known newline state you can freely convert back to CRLF using `:crlf_newline`. eg: to convert a file of unknown (possibly mixed) ending to `CRLF` (for example), read it in binary mode, then :

```
s.encode(s.encoding, universal_newline: true).encode(s.encoding, crlf_newline: true)
```

Comment: You don't need to include the first `s.encoding`, a simple `s.encode(universal_newline: true)` or `s.encode(crlf_newline: true)` does the trick. This helped me with a project today.

Comment: @Donovan - You're _probably_ right, however the docs say that the version without an explicit encoding will transcode to `Encoding.default_internal`, which may or may not be what you want.  My version will conservatively preserve your current encoding.

Comment: true and you make a good point, but in most cases the default is fine, after all, that's what `String.new` uses.  So, in my case (and I could argue most cases), it would be redundant.

Comment: This is apparently much faster than other methods (takes 40% less time than gsub method whereas split-join takes about 40% more time). I compared this to: `s.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")`,  `s.gsub("\r\n", "\n").gsub("\r", "\n")` (about same speed), and `s.split(/\r\n?/).join("\n")`

Answer (score 4):

I think the cleanest solution would be to use a regular expression:

```
s.gsub! /\r\n?/, "\n"
```

Comment: oops, this has a trap: double line breaks like `\n\n` will become `\n`.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out, seems jleedev was a bit faster though.

Answer (score -9):

Try opening them on NetBeans IDE - Its asked me before, on one of the projects I've opened from elsewhere, if I wanted to fix the line endings.  I think there might be a menu option to do it too, but that would be the first thing I would try.

Comment: thanks, but this isn't a one-off; this is for processing data in Ruby, not processing Ruby files.