# Is there a built-in method in Ruby to convert LF to CRLF in a string and vice versa?

Tags: ruby, control-characters

We can certainly do it by

`string.chomp+"\r\n"`

but I'm wondering is there an elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

This prior answer seems to suggest use of gsub (regex replacement)

[Normalizing line endings in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836046/normalizing-line-endings-in-ruby)