# How to write DOS line endings to a file from Unix

Tags: ruby, windows, file, unix, encoding

My Unix Ruby program needs to write a file that will be read by
SqlServer running on Windows.  I need for the lines I write to this
file to end in `\r\n`, the DOS/Windows line ending, rather than `\n`,
the Unix line ending.  I want this to happen without me having to
manually add the \r to the end of each line.

## The starting point

If my program writes to the file like this:

```
File.open("/tmp/foo", "w") do |file|
  file.puts "stuff"
end
```

Then the file has Unix line endings:

```
$ od -c foo
0000000   s   t   u   f   f  \n
```

That is expected, since my program is running on Unix.  But I
need for this file (and this file only) to have DOS line endings.

## Adding the \r to each line manually

If I add the \r to each line manually:

```
File.open("/tmp/foo", "w") do |file|
  file.puts "stuff\r"
end
```

Then the file has DOS line endings:

```
$ od -c /tmp/foo
0000000   s   t   u   f   f  \r  \n
```

This works, but has to be repeated for each line I want to write.

## Using String#encode

As shown by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20984551/238886), I can modify the string using
String#encode before writing it:

```
File.open("/tmp/foo", "w") do |file|
  file.puts "alpha\nbeta\n".encode(crlf_newline: true)
end
```

This results in DOS line endings:

```
$ od -c /tmp/foo
0000000   a   l   p   h   a  \r  \n   b   e   t   a  \r  \n
```

This has the advantage that if I am writing multiple lines at once,
one call to #encode will change all the line endings for that one
write.  However, it's verbose, and I still have to specify the line
ending for every write.

**How can I cause each `puts` to an open file *in Unix* to end
the line in the Windows `\r\n` line ending rather than the Unix '\n'
line ending?**

I am running Ruby 2.3.1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an option for this, the same one you're using on `encode` also works with `File.open`:

```
File.open('/tmp/foo', mode: 'w', crlf_newline: true) do |file|
  file.puts("alpha")
  file.puts("beta")
end
```

This option not only ends lines in `\r\n`, it also translates any explicit `\n` into `\r\n`.  So this:

```
file.puts("alpha\nbar")
```

will write `alpha\r\nbar\r\b`

Comment: Note the `crlf_newline` option also works with `Tempfile`